# How to Pass dynamic condition in where clause in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can I write a dynamic query, and how to pass it into a where condition?

```
var query = "Name = 'Test'";

//Get data by passing dynamic query
var result = from Table01 in T0001
    where(query)
    select Table01 ;
```

Comment: There are plenty of questions on similar subject which you likely already seen. Please [edit] your post to clarify why usual approach building an expression tree does not work for your case and what exactly you want as an input to your "dynamic where condition". This will add missing details and make it more answerable.

Comment: I voted to reopen because I can't see any lack of focus in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) so that you can build query dynamically:

```
var query = "Name == \"Test\"";

var result = dbContext.T0001.Where(query).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You add a reference to [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) or [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) depending on the kind of project you have (it's a lot easier to get the deprecated package to play nice with a framework winforms project for example) and the flavour of .net it uses - see https://dynamic-linq.net/ for example use.

The code would be pretty much as you have there except you wouldn't use apostrophes to delimit the string because apostrophes are for chars. You could use `\"` but the more typical way to do it is like

```
Where("Name = @0", "Test")
```